# Python List Indexing and Returning the Item

Tags: python, list, methods, cnf

So this is a simple question that I seem to be confused on, i've been working on this input problem and trying to store certain parts of a users input into segmented lists.

The user input is going to input a CNF (conjunctive normal form).
Example: + = or, * = and, anything within the ( and ) is a clause

(A+B)*(C+D)

So since this input has two clauses I need to store each clause as their own item into a list. I'm having trouble figuring how to traverse through the list I have already made and getting my if statement to segment each clause, I understand logically how it's supposed to work, I just need help with syntax and methods associated with storing something dynamically into a list.

I understand whole heartedly why the index is not working, i'm basically looking for the reverse of what index method is, i need to find my item associated with my index.

For example, when I find an open paranthesis "(" i need to start to store a new clause into my list, so far I only found how to return the index itself and not the item via the index. This should be a simple solution to this but I simply can't find anything that associated with displaying this method wise.

```
cnf = input("CNF: ")
cnf_input = list(cnf)

cnf_input_len = len(cnf_input)
i = 0
##this count resets when it sees a ")"
claus_count = 0
while i < cnf_input_len:

    claus_list = cnf_input.append(i)
    print(cnf_input.index("B"))
    if cnf_input.index(i)=="(":
        print('Cut here')
    i=i+1
```

My code as a guideline

Comment: Are you always expecting two clauses? or can it be any number of clauses?

Comment: Like i said, it's dynamic, so I need to allocate it accordingly to what the user inputs. There's only 26 literals (variables: A, B, C...) they can input for their input, but the clauses can be as many as they want.

What operator am I storing? The "=="?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are over complicating it. Simply use [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) followed by [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to get the individual clauses in a list

```
>>> [elem.strip('()') for elem in "(A+B)*(C+D)".split("*")]
['A+B', 'C+D']
```

You can even extend it to get the individual literals of the clauses as a tuple or lists to get a list of lists

```
>>> [elem.strip('()').split('+') for elem in "(A+B)*(C+D)".split("*")]
[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]
```

You may even want to experiment with regex

```
>>> re.findall(r'([^()]+?)\+([^()]+?)', "(A+B)*(C+D)")
[('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D')]
```

Comment: To expand on this, is this possible to translate this with a dictionary, I need each value of the literal that i'm using to either be 1 or 0 (1 being true, 0 being false). I need to have my input set up this way to check what each literal needs to be in order for the entire CNF to be true, and i'm doing it this way in such that each clause will at least have a 1 (which makes the clause itself true).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to determine the starting/stopping points in the formula.

```
import re

formula = r'\(([\w+\d+])([*+-/])([\w+\d+])\)([*+-/])\(([\w+\d+])([*+-/])([\w+\d+])\)'
solve_for = '(A+B)*(C+D)'
splitter = re.match(formula, solve_for).groups()
```

Where splitter is now a tuple of the user's input:

```
('A', '+', 'B', '*', 'C', '+', 'D')
```